# Error while installing MegaSync on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dpkg, 20.04, mega

I am trying to install MegaSync on my new ubuntu 20.04 installation =). They already have a version out for ubuntu 20.04. (See https://mega.nz/sync). However, when I try to install it with `sudo dpkg -i megasync-xUbuntu_20.04_amd64.deb` I get a big list of dependency errors. It seems to me Megasync is missing some packages. However when I open the software updater it says there are no new updates that need to be done. I am not so experienced with Ubuntu yet so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Selecting previously unselected package megasync.
(Reading database ... 195014 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack megasync-xUbuntu_20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking megasync (4.3.1-15.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of megasync:
 megasync depends on libc-ares2 (>= 1.7.4); however:
  Package libc-ares2 is not installed.
 megasync depends on libcrypto++6; however:
  Package libcrypto++6 is not installed.
 megasync depends on libmediainfo0v5 (>= 0.7.56); however:
  Package libmediainfo0v5 is not installed.
 megasync depends on libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2); however:
  Package libqt5core5a is not installed.
 megasync depends on libqt5dbus5 (>= 5.0.2); however:
  Package libqt5dbus5 is not installed.
 megasync depends on libqt5gui5 (>= 5.8.0) | libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.8.0); however:
  Package libqt5gui5 is not installed.
  Package libqt5gui5-gles is not installed.
 megasync depends on libqt5network5 (>= 5.1.0); however:
  Package libqt5network5 is not installed.
 megasync depends on libqt5svg5 (>= 5.6.0~beta); however:
  Package libqt5svg5 is not installed.
 megasync depends on libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.11.0~rc1); however:
  Package libqt5widgets5 is not installed.
 megasync depends on libzen0v5 (>= 0.4.31-2~); however:
  Package libzen0v5 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package megasync (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 megasync
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `apt` / `apt-get` instead of `dpkg`. They will install dependencies for package:

```
sudo apt install ./megasync-xUbuntu_20.04_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks! The `./` is very important, otherwise it doesn't work!

Answer (score -1):

None of the solutions I found in the web worked so I tried the following:

I downloaded libcrypto++9 from here, and installed it as a .deb.
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libc/libcrypto++/libcrypto++9_5.6.1-6_amd64.deb

The same for libc6 from:
http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.31-4_amd64.deb

Then I downloaded libqt5gui5-gles_5.15.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb from
http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/q/qtbase-opensource-src-gles/libqt5gui5-gles_5.15.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb

You should do it with any package that is missing in your own configuration. I recomend this website to find them: https://pkgs.org/

Comment: This answer can break a system since it not only advises installing software from `.deb` files, but the answer also suggests installing packages from other distributions.  Additionally, pkgs.org is not an official mirror or source for Ubuntu software.  When there are official sources like https://packages.ubuntu.com, referring users to unofficial software sources poses an unnecessary risk.  This answer also lacks [formatting](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting), which is needed so the names of packages can be distinguished from the surrounding text.